# Insert into JPA a Set

Tags: java, jpa

I am doing a Database with JPA. I defined the classes and now i am inserting data. This are my tables:

```
public class Cliente {
@Id
@Column(name = "DNI", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String DNI;
@Column(name= "Nombre", nullable = false, length= 20)
private String nombre;
@Column(name= "Apellidos", nullable = false,length= 50)
private String apellidos;
@Column(name= "FechaNac" , nullable = false)
private Date FechaNac; //uso Date de SQL ya que es para una base de datos.
@Column(name= "Direccion" , nullable = false, length = 40)
private String direccion;
@Column(name = "email" , nullable= true, length=50)
private String email;
@Column(name = "Telefono" , nullable=false,length=15)
private String telefono;

@ManyToMany(cascade ={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="es_titular",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="DNI"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="numerocuenta"))
private Set<Cuenta> cuentas;
public Cliente(){}

public Set<Cuenta> getCuentas(){
    return cuentas;
}

public void setCuentas(Set<Cuenta> a){
    cuentas=a;
}
}
```

and the other table:

```
package Entidades;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name="Cuenta")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="discriminator",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)

 //Si es especializacion total, no se pone.
//@DiscriminatorValue("D")
public class Cuenta {
@Id
@Column(name="numerocuenta", nullable=false, length=15)
private String numerocuenta;
@Column(name="FechaCreacion", nullable=false)
private Date FechaCreacion;
@Column(name="Saldo", nullable=false, precision=2)
private float Saldo;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy ="cuentas")
private Set<Cliente> clientes;
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="cuenta")
private Set<Operacion> operaciones;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, mappedBy="cuentaObjetivo")
private Set<Transferencia> transferencias;

public Set<Cliente> getClientes(){
    return clientes;
}
public void setClientes(Set<Cliente> s){
    clientes=s;
}
public Set<Operacion> getOperaciones(){
    return operaciones;
}

public void setOperaciones(Set<Operacion> s){
    operaciones=s;
}


public Set<Transferencia> getTransferencias(){
    return transferencias;
}

public void setTransfrencias(Set<Transferencia> s){
    transferencias=s;
}
}
```

I have eliminate some attributes to make de code more clean.

Then, when I insert into Cuentas, i am do this:

```
Set<Cliente> clientes=new HashSet<Cliente>();
    clientes.add(cliente1);
    clientes.add(cliente2);

    trans.begin();

    Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
    cuenta.setNumerocuenta("343434");
    cuenta.setFechaCreacion(new Date(2013,05,05));
    cuenta.setSaldo(0);
    cuenta.setClientes(clientes);
    em.persist(cuenta);
    trans.commit();
```

With the Cliente and Cuenta created. But when I look the database, I dont see the Set Clientes in any table.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: My objective is when I insert a Set in any table (Cliente or Cuenta) in the jointable es_titular, appears. The structure of es_titular is:  DNI varchar2(10 char), numerocuenta varchar2(15 char)

Comment: It should have a Cliente table on your database. Please check that.

Comment: In my database I have a Cliente table and a Cuenta table.

Comment: so the Clientes from the Set should be inserted in that table.

Comment: But, the jointable es_titular its empty, and I think that it will be with data. I want to do that when I insert a Set, in the jointable appears.

Comment: ok, does the data is inserted in the Clientes table? can you post the structure of your 'es_titular' table?

Comment: the table es_titular is created with the condition of the jointable in Cliente: DNI varchar2(10 char), numerocuenta varchar2(15 char)

Comment: ok, everything looks fine... my suggestion would be to test creating the Cliente and setting the Cuenta to it, so save the Cliente object instead of the Cuenta object as the cascade configuration is set in the Cliente object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bidirectional association. Every bidirectional association has an owner side and an inverse side. The inverse side is the side with the `mappedBy` attribute. The owner side is the other side. JPA doesn't care about the inverse side.

So if you want to associate a cliente with a cuenta, you must add the cuenta to the cliente, because cuente is the owner side of the association. The good practice, generally, is to maintain both sides of the association, even if JPA only cares about the owner side, because

- you're sure not to forget the owner side
- it makes the object graph coherent

Comment: Maintain both, do you mean to create the @JoinColumn in both tables?

Comment: No. I mean that if you add a cliente to a cuenta, you should also add the cuenta to the cliente, to have a coherent object graph.